# bootstrap model is not displaying handsontable data

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, handsontable

On click of particular cell of handsontable it opens a bootstrap model but it is not showing data, because i don't have any data-toggle="" data-target="" in html, how to display data

```
function gettData(columnNbr,rowNbr){
        var details=[];         
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#myModal").modal({
                     //keyboard: true,
                     //backdrop: "static",`enter code here`
                     //show:false,
                }).on("show", function(){

                });
                $scope.getHOTData();
                //I am calling method to load data for handson table
            });

    }

HTML content
 <div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Title</b></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div htable id="idHOT" data="data"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please correct the title of this question so more it can reach more people and help you get the answer faster.

Comment: Please include your Handsontable/modal trigger code as well.